# StorageFile type not in Windows.Storage

Tags: uwp, storagefile

I have to use StorageFile in my program for hololens.
I've installed the UwpDesktop package.
I also have the System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll and also Windows.Storage.dll in my .Net Core Assembly folder.

How do i proceed to use StorageFile in my code.

Below is the screenshot of the error.
[image: StorageFile error]

Comment: What type of project are you trying to create? If you are creating a "Windows Runtime Component" (=library for use in UWP projects) the right reference should be added automatically.

In other project types you would need to manually add a reference to "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.{SDK-VERSION}.0\Windows.winmd".

Comment: .NET Core is not compatible with UWP. Adding a "Desktop" extension won't work on Hololens either. (Unless these are Unity concepts?)